# API POST request returns 404 NOT FOUND PAGE on postman and Laravel

Tags: laravel, api, postman, laravel-routing, laravel-api

I created this api api routes on laravel..

```
Route::get('/items', [ItemController::class, 'index']);
Route::prefix('/item', function () {
Route::post('/store', [ItemController::class, 'store']);
Route::put('/{id}', [ItemController::class, 'update']);
Route::delete('/store', [ItemController::class, 'destroy']);
```

when I use GET requests on postman, everything works great but when I use POST requests I get 404 not Found Page!

[image]

and this is my store function on Item Controller

```
    public function store(Request $request)
{


    $newItem = new Item();
    $newItem->name = request()->item["name"];
    $newItem->save();

    return $newItem;
}
```

Comment: Your routes is syntactically incorrect. Please update it.

Comment: what wrong on my routes?

Comment: Why did you change it to an image? the route prefix syntax is wrong: You need to use `->group()` https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-group-prefixes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the routes group should be written in this way

```
Route::prefix('item')->group(function () {
    Route::post('/store', [ItemController::class , 'store']);
    ...
});
```

Comment: I'd also add to this, look into using Route::resource(), since you are using the typical URLs, Laravel can add them in for you automatically and clean up your routes file a bit.